# Javascript Button to expand site menu on phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive

i'm using an online mega menu for my site, the entire code is [here](http://codepen.io/ahsanrathore/pen/wMRwpZ)

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ic menu">
<span class="line"></span>
<span class="line"></span>
<span class="line"></span>
</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ic close"></a>
```

On mobile it has a button like an app button for opening the menu.
The problem is that it's working on desktop but it doesn't open on my smartphone.

It's any way to solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: what is your javascript onclick code? how do you want to open the menu?

Comment: I don't have an onclick code. 
For onclick, i tried with onclick="return false;". 
But i don't know if the void / onclick code is the problem or the <a href> html code. I'm mostly beginner at this..

Comment: This is pure CSS solution that uses :focus CSS styles to change its view. JavaScript code here won't help you. Can you tell us on what device and browser version this doesn't work?

Comment: Iphone 5, Chrome version 50.0.26

Comment: So the real problem is that you can't open the menu, right? Or if is something else please explain here deeply.

Comment: @ValentinBorisov yes, I can't open the menu

Comment: @TaviOcan: Have you tried with :active css?

Comment: @ParagBhayani I'm looking right now on how to use the :active property, thanks. But how this should work? I can open and close the menu with this?

Comment: You can add this style: .ic.close { z-index: 18; } I think you can't click on "menu" icon because it's behind the "close" icon which hasn't any z-index set. It's definitely browser issue. But you can try with the trick that @ParagBhayani's suggested you too.

Comment: Here to open menu using CSS developer has used :hover, and hover doesn't occur in phones, so you need to replace :hover css with :active for phone

Comment: @TaviOcan: See my answer to get the exact idea about...

Comment: @TaviOcan did you try with the CSS hack which I mentioned?

Comment: @ValentinBorisov i tried the z-index for ic.close. Didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here to open menu using CSS developer has used :hover, and hover doesn't occur in phones, so you need to replace :hover css with :active for phone, See [codepen](http://codepen.io/ParagBhayani/pen/pbvgYb)

```
Note: I have checked this in landscape mode of my phone
```

```css
/* Body Styles */
body { 
  margin: 0px; 
  padding: 0px; 
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
  background-color: #fff;  
}

header.dark blockquote { color:#fff; }
header.light blockquote { color:#000; }

blockquote { 
  max-width: 1000px; 
  margin:0 auto;
  font-size: 16px; 
  border-left: 0px;
  padding:  20px ;
}

blockquote h2 { padding-right: 40px; margin: 0px; }
header.dark blockquote a {color: orange; text-decoration: underline;}
header.light blockquote a {text-decoration: underline;}
header { min-height: 450px; }
header.dark { background-color: #444; }
header.light { background-color: #fff; }

/* Navigation Styles */
nav { position: relative;  }
header.dark nav { background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5); }
header.light nav { background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }

ul.main-nav { 
  list-style-type: none; 
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 0px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.main-nav > li { 
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0; 
}

ul.main-nav > li > a { 
  display: block; 
  padding: 20px 30px; 
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.main-nav > li:hover { background-color: #f9f9f9; }
ul.main-nav > li:hover > a { color: #333; font-weight: 400; }

ul.main-nav > li ul.sub-menu-lists {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type : none;
  display:block;
}

ul.main-nav > li ul.sub-menu-lists > li {
  padding: 2px 0;
}

ul.main-nav > li ul.sub-menu-lists > li > a {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.ic {
  position: fixed; 
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  right: 25px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  top:0px;
  outline: none;
}

.ic.close { 
  opacity: 0; 
  font-size: 0px; 
  font-weight: 300; 
  color: #fff;
  top:8px;
  height:40px;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
}

/* Menu Icons for Devices*/
.ic.menu { top:25px; z-index : 20; }

.ic.menu .line { 
  height: 4px; 
  width: 100%; 
  display: block; 
  margin-bottom: 6px; 
}
.ic.menu .line-last-child { margin-bottom: 0px;  }

.sub-menu-head { margin: 10px 0; }
.banners-area { margin-top: 20px; padding-top: 15px; }


@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .sub-menu-head { color:orange; }
  .ic.menu { display: block; }
  header.dark .ic.menu .line { background-color: #fff; } 
  header.light .ic.menu .line { background-color: #000; }
  .ic.menu .line {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    -ms-transform-origin: center center;
    transform-origin: center center;
  }
  .ic.menu:focus .line { background-color: #fff !important; }
  
  .ic.menu:focus .line:nth-child(1) { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg); 
  }
  
  .ic.menu:focus .line:nth-child(2) { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg); 
    margin-top: -10px;
  }
  
  .ic.menu:focus .line:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(15px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .ic.menu:focus{ outline: none; }
  .ic.menu:focus ~ .ic.close { opacity: 1; z-index : 21;  outline: none;  }
  
  /*
  
  .ic.menu:focus ~ .ic.close { opacity: 1.0; z-index : 21;  }
  .ic.close:focus { opacity: 0; }
  */
  .ic.menu:focus { opacity: 1;  }
  

  nav { background-color: transparent; }
  
 /* Main Menu for Handheld Devices  */
  ul.main-nav {
    z-index:2; 
    padding: 50px 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    /*CSS animation applied : Slide from Right*/
   -webkit-transition-property: background, width;
    -moz-transition-property: background, width;
    -o-transition-property: background, width;
    transition-property: background, width;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
   -moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;
   -o-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
  }
  
  .ic.menu:focus ~ .main-nav { width: 300px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1); }
  
  ul.main-nav > * { 
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    -moz-transition-property: opacity;
    -o-transition-property: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
   -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
   -o-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .ic.menu:focus ~ .main-nav > * {opacity: 1;}
  
  ul.main-nav > li > a:after {display: none;}
  ul.main-nav > li:first-child { border-radius: 0px; }
  ul.main-nav > li {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  }
  
  ul.main-nav > li > a { font-weight: 600; }
  
  ul.main-nav > li ul.sub-menu-lists > li a { color: #eee; font-size: 14px; }
  .sub-menu-head { font-size: 16px;}
  ul.main-nav > li:hover { background-color: transparent;  }
  ul.main-nav > li:hover > a {color: #fff; text-decoration: none; font-weight: 600;}
 .ic.menu:focus ~ ul.main-nav > li > div.sub-menu-block {
    border-left: 0px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 0px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  
  .sub-menu-block { padding: 0 30px; }
  .banners-area { padding-bottom: 0px;  }
  .banners-area div { margin-bottom: 15px;  }
  .banners-area { border-top: 1px solid #444; }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:769px) {
  .ic.menu { display: none; }
  /* Main Menu for Desktop Devices  */
  ul.main-nav { display: block; position: relative; }
  .sub-menu-block { padding: 15px; }
  
  /* Sub Menu */
  ul.main-nav > li > div.sub-menu-block { 
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #333;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index : 3;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  opacity: 0;
    
  /*CSS animation applied for sub menu : Slide from Top */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
  -ms-transform-origin: top center;
  transform-origin: top center;
  
  }
  
  ul.main-nav > li:hover > div.sub-menu-block,   ul.main-nav > li:active > div.sub-menu-block{ 
    background-color: #f9f9f9; 
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  
  ul.main-nav > li > div.sub-menu-block > * {
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    -moz-transition-property: opacity;
    -o-transition-property: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
   -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
   -o-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  ul.main-nav > li:hover > div.sub-menu-block > *,ul.main-nav > li:active > div.sub-menu-block > * {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .sub-menu-head { font-size: 20px;}
  
  /* List Separator: Outer Border */
  header.dark ul.main-nav > li > a { border-right: 1px solid #bbb; }
  header.light ul.main-nav > li > a { border-right: 1px solid #666; }
  
  /* List Separator: Inner Border */
  ul.main-nav > li > a:after {
    content: '';
    width: 1px;
    height: 62px;
    position: absolute;
    right:0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index : 2;
  }
  header.dark ul.main-nav > li > a:after { background-color: #777; }
  header.light ul.main-nav > li > a:after { background-color: #999; }
  
  /* Drop Down/Up Arrow for Mega Menu */
  ul.main-nav > li > a.mega-menu > span { display: block; vertical-align: middle; }
  ul.main-nav > li > a.mega-menu > span:after {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #fff;
    content: '';
    background-color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  ul.main-nav > li:hover > a.mega-menu span:after,ul.main-nav > li:active > a.mega-menu span:after {
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #666;
  }
  .banners-area { border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }
}
```

```html
<!-- Available in two variations: "light" and "dark" | Change <header> class to see impact. -->
<header class="dark">
  <nav role="navigation">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ic menu">
      <span class="line"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ic close"></a>
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li class="top-level-link">
        <a><span>Home</span></a>      
      </li> 
      
      <li class="top-level-link">
        <a class="mega-menu"><span>Products</span></a>
        <div class="sub-menu-block">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
              <h2 class="sub-menu-head">Clothing</h2>
              <ul class="sub-menu-lists">
                <li><a>Mens</a></li>
                <li><a>Womens</a></li>
                <li><a>Kids</a></li>
                <li><a>New Born</a></li>
                <li><a>View All</a></li>
              </ul>           
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
              <h2 class="sub-menu-head">Handbags</h2>
              <ul class="sub-menu-lists">
                <li><a>Wallets</a></li>
                <li><a>Athletic bag</a></li>
                <li><a>Backpack</a></li>
                <li><a>Bucket Bag</a></li>
                <li><a>View All</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
              <h2 class="sub-menu-head">Shoes</h2>
              <ul class="sub-menu-lists">
                <li><a>Mens</a></li>
                <li><a>Womens</a></li>
                <li><a>Kids</a></li>
                <li><a>View All</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="row banners-area">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
              <img src="http://devitems.com/tf/teemo-preview/teemo/img/banner/banner-menu1.jpg" width="100%;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
              <img src="http://devitems.com/tf/teemo-preview/teemo/img/banner/banner-menu1.jpg" width="100%;">
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="top-level-link">
        <a><span>Services<span></a>    
      </li>
      <li class="top-level-link">
        <a class="mega-menu"><span>About</span></a>
        <div class="sub-menu-block">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
              <h2 class="sub-menu-head">Company</h2>
              <ul class="sub-menu-lists">
                <li><a>About</a></li>
                <li><a>Mission</a></li>
                <li><a>Community</a></li>
                <li><a>Team</a></li>
              </ul>           
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
              <h2 class="sub-menu-head">Media</h2>
              <ul class="sub-menu-lists">
                <li><a>News</a></li>
                <li><a>Events</a></li>
                <li><a>Blog</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
              <h2 class="sub-menu-head">Careers</h2>
              <ul class="sub-menu-lists">
                <li><a>New Opportunities</a></li>
                <li><a>Life @ Company</a></li>
                <li><a>Why Join Us?</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="row banners-area">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
              <img src="http://devitems.com/tf/teemo-preview/teemo/img/banner/banner-menu1.jpg" width="100%;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
              <img src="http://devitems.com/tf/teemo-preview/teemo/img/banner/banner-menu1.jpg" width="100%;">
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="top-level-link">
        <a><span>Contact</span></a>      
      </li>
    </ul> 
  </nav>
    <blockquote>
      <h2>Responsive Mega Menu - CSS3</h2>
      <br>
      <strong>Cross Browser Support:</strong> <br>
      Tested on Chrome (48.0.2564.109 m), Firefox, IE 11, Chrome Browser for Android 5.1.1 (Xperia Z2), Windows Phone 8.0 for Lumia 720
      <br><br>
      <strong>Expected Support for Desktop:</strong><br>
      IE9+, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari for Mac, <a href="http://caniuse.com/#search=transform" target="_blank">See All Browsers</a>
      <br><br>
      <strong>Expected Support for Handheld:</strong><br>
      Chrome Browser for Android, Android Browser, Safari for iOS, Windows Phone 8.1, <a href="http://caniuse.com/#search=transform" target="_blank">See All Browsers</a>
      <br>
      <hr>
      Available in two variations: "light" and "dark" | Change &lt;header&gt; class to see impact.
    </blockquote>
</header>
```

[image]

Comment: Ohh, I'm sorry for misleading... So the menu buttons are working fine. When you shrink the window (aka when you are on mobile), the menu is on the left, like an app menu.
The problem is the button for opening the left menu on phone is not working. The menu isn't apear at all..

Comment: Man, he speaks about the mobile version of the navigation :)

Comment: which button you are talking about @TaviOcan

Comment: On a lower resolution the menu is changing in an "app menu", with a button in the right top corner. You press that to open the entire menu.
But it's not working..
PS: i tried with z-index, not working.. It doesn't work on Safari too..

Comment: @ParagBhayani umm, I will check on another phone. I can't understand why it's not working on mine.. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue was resolved

The problem is with IOS

```
.ic.menu:focus // If you want a real focus state to a element,
               // you can add a tabindex attribute to it.
```

EXAMPLE:

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ic menu" tabindex="1">
<span class="line"></span>
<span class="line"></span>
<span class="line"></span>
</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ic close" tabindex="1"></a>
```